# How do I get white text on green background in a graphviz table?

Tags: graphviz

How do I get white text on green background in a graphviz table label? `fontcolor` doesn't seem to work...:

```
digraph foo {

    id1 [shape=none,label=<
        <table border="1" cellborder="0" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="green" fontcolor="white">hello</td>
                <td>world</td>
            </tr>
        </table>>];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
digraph foo {

id1 [shape=none,label=<
    <table border="1" cellborder="0" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="green"><font color="white">hello</font></td>
            <td>world</td>
        </tr>
    </table>>];
}
```

[image]